# What to do if your question is closed as “Too broad” even if it isn't?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons, deleted-questions, closed-questions

**Context**

A while ago I asked a question about compiling go to C [[click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55419462/use-clang-instead-of-gcc-for-golang-to-c-compilation)], and whether or not I could use a different c-compiler then the default. I received 2 comments, both asking me about the legitimacy of my question and questioners assumed that GO "cannot be compiled to C".

I provided both questioners with a link to the build options of go where it states you can create a "c-shared" library. To build this library by default GCC is used and I wanted to know if CLang could be used instead. In the meantime someone had provided me with an answer to the question in the comment-section.

I then noticed my question had been down-voted and subsequently closed as "too broad". Which is complete non-sense, so I provided argumentation in the comments below my question why it wasn't "too broad". Afterwards I voted to reopen the question.

Today I find that the question has been deleted because it has no answers and 2 downvotes. I am perplexed about this chain of events.

The down-voters obviously don't know Go well enough and the question did have an answer but it was not possible to list it as an answer since the question had been closed as "too broad". I received no suggests nor warnings as to what exactly was "too broad" about the question so I couldn't change any part of it.

In my argumentation I even state that the question can ben answered with "yes or no", since I can either switch out the compiler or I can't.

**Question**

Now to my question, how can I do something against these types of occurrences, which I feel are based on the lack of knowledge of moderators?

**Screenshot for <10k user**

[image]

Comment: _"The down-voters obviously don't know Go well enough "_ Votes are anonymous, so that is never a proper argument here.

Comment: Please don't assume that voters (of any kind) don't understand your question or don't have the expertise to judge it. Even if users don't have a single SO answer about this language/topic, that doesn't mean at all that they don't know that technology. (I, for example, have almost 0 score in C#, but in my daily work I write C# code for most of  the last eight years). If you want any detailed discussion about your question, you should add a link to it.

Comment: @E_net4 You're right. Though I doubt people would down-vote if they don't have a reason to do so. To not supply that reason yet still down-vote seems odd to me. So my assumption is that the down-voters are the same as those commenting on the question. Since stackoverflow is about helping someone out.

Comment: Votes are not supposed to be accompanied by a comment explaining anything. So you shouldn't expect that they do.

Comment: That false assumption of commenters being the downvoters is one of the reasons why [feedback should not be made mandatory](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357436/1233251).

Comment: Also, it's likely that "moderators" (as in, community elected moderators, designated by a diamond icon) were not involved, but simply other regular users (which you could call user-moderators, but it seems unlikely that's what you meant).

Comment: *Since stackoverflow is about helping someone out*: That's not the primary mission of SO. The big goal is to create a "library of detailed answers to every question about programming". Helping askers is a nice by-product of this.

Comment: @double-beep Will do. Should I strike-through the user-names? Since I'm not out to make damage reputations. I just want to know what to do in cases like this.

Comment: In the hypothetical case that a question is closed for invalid reasons, you can plead a case on meta and if people agree they will cast reopen votes. Alternatively you could drop into the [SOCVR](https://socvr.org/) chat room.

Comment: Generally: if a question is closed and you want to contest the closure, you should edit the question to show address the close reason (either by improving the question so the closure no longer applies, or by addressing the close reason and explaining **why** it doesn't apply). The first edit after a closure will push the question to the re-open queue, where other users can vote to re-open if they think it shouldn't be closed.

Comment: [Why is "Is it possible to:" a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7274/31260)

Comment: @Gimby Could you explain why it's structured that way? The reason I'm asking is I feel I was given zero feedback on what to change about the question, before it was closed.

Comment: @gnat Agreed. Though that hardly qualifies a question as "too broad".

Comment: @yivi It's not so much about the closure itself. I can live with a closed question, or remarks about how to phrase or rephrase it. The thing I don't understand is why I was not given any feedback about what was not clear or "too broad" about the question. If I don't know what people don't understand I can't alter my question to fit the rules or resolve the supposed violation.

Comment: @BDL *That's not the primary mission of SO* . I don't understand the reasoning behind this. Why would anyone go through the trouble of creating a gigantic database with questions and detailed answers about programming if the intend isn't to help out a fellow human-being. Might as well host the library privately then instead of on a public domain.

Comment: [1/2]Things I note when reading the question and comments: 1) stating "in an answer to another question" without linking to it is useless. Noone can see what is stated there and in which context. Almost the same as saying "I did research" without showing what one has found. 2) Your comments should instead be an edit to your question. 3) Explain that actually didn't mean "compile to C" but "compile to C library". 4) Show what you are currently executing. Go can compile to "C-Archive" or to "C-Shared Library" (don't know which you are actually using).

Comment: *Things I note when reading the question and comments*. This is exactly what I was looking for. I can change these things and I would have. I received no feedback whatsoever before closure, so there was no way for me to apply this to avoid closure in the first place.

Comment: About the mission of SO: The goal is to create a library where anything can be found and can be used by a large number of future visitors. Helping *a* human-being (or the asker) is not the main goal. Helping a large number of people is.

Comment: *Helping a large number of people is.* Then it's about helping more than one person. The same reasoning would apply, right? No-one benefits from a poorly phrased question. So receiving feedback, like you provided, would have helped more people and avoided the deletion/closure. Now I was left hanging with no clue what was wrong about the question.

Comment: SO gets far too many questions to guarantee personalized help with each and every one of them.  Most people will try to focus on questions they feel are good uses of their time, and just downvote and close the ones that aren't.  Requiring specific feedback such as comments to cast judgement on a post means you just get less voting, and that declines the quality of the site.

Comment: @Byebye But you *were* given feedback on what was wrong with your question.  Your question was closed for being Too Broad.  You can't claim that you weren't given feedback on your question when you were.  You can say you don't agree with it.  That's different.

Comment: To give a bit more credence to what fbueckert is saying: keep an eye on the home page. Look at the amount of stuff that would help no one but the asker. Start commenting on them and explain and guide and mentor and...... Tell me after 3 months how you feel? This is just not scalable:/. That's why we have automated systems like the closure to provide standardized feedback

Comment: @Servy I was given feedback on the reason for the closure. I have no problem with the closure. I have a problem with the fact I received no feedback on what  was "too broad" about the question. If I don't receive feedback on what to change about a question it will remain "too broad". Since I don't know what part is unclear. If you're going to mark the question as too broad you probably know why, I don't. How can I rephrase a question if I don't know what's wrong? Especially if I feel it's not too broad. I can't go beyond my own current limitations. That's why I needed feedback.

Comment: @Byebye: "*I have a problem with the fact I received no feedback on what was "too broad" about the question.*" Both of the comments your questions received talked about compiling Go to C. As such, you should have realized what the misunderstanding was. Which in fact you did, because you posted a link that clarified what you were really talking about. But you never actually *fixed your question* to say that you were asking about compiling to a "C shared library", not to "C". And all of that happened while your question was *open*.

Comment: @NicolBolas *Which in fact you did, because you posted a link that clarified what you were really talking about.*
No I didn't realize that this was the issue with the question. I provided them with the information I thought "they" were lacking. It didn't occur to me that this was the information they would have liked to see in the question itself. No-one told me and I can't act on something that doesn't occur to me. I don't have that kind of power over my brain to always have it make the right inferences. That's why I asked for elaboration.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I provided both questioners with a link to the build options of go where it states you can create a "c-shared" library.

That is *not what you asked about*. In this context, a "c-shared library" is just a binary shared library whose calling conventions are the standard for C, and thus are compatible/accessible by anything that can speak C's calling conventions.

Your question talked about compilation "to c". As in, C *the language*, not C the calling convention. That task is typically called "cross-compilation", and it exceedingly complicated. Also, there's no compilation mode from Go to C the language. As such, your question is far too broad.

The best way to avoid this in the future is to take people at their word. If they say "Where in the Go toolchain does it compile Go to C?", you should assume that something in the wording of your question made them think that you were asking about cross-compilation. Look at your question from a dispassionate perspective and find out what is making them think that. And then make it clear that this is not what you're talking about *in the question*, not in a comment below.

Comment: I agree and I should have worded it in the manner you describe. However, how could I have rephrased my question in that manner if the question gets closed and deleted well before I get a response from the commenters?

I can't clarify anything if I don't know which information is lacking. I don't mind having to rephrase, that's how I learn. I simply don't get why a question gets closed in this manner without telling someone how they could narrow the scope of the question.

Thanks for the response, I will mark your answer as the answer to my question.

Comment: @Byebye: "*how could I have rephrased my question in that manner if the question gets closed and deleted well before I get a response from the commenters?*" That didn't happen. The question was closed ~18 hours after you posted it. It was commented on well before then, so you did know what information was lacking. As evidenced by the fact that you *responded to those comments*, and your responses were posted *while the question was open*. You had ample opportunity to fix your question before it was closed. And pretending otherwise is unhelpful.

Comment: *That didn't happen* That did happen.
After arguing why I felt the question wasn't to broad I asked: "Please elaborate how I should alter the question"

*The question was closed ~18 hours after you posted it.*
I have work during the day and I'm not looking at notifications from stack-overflow most of the time.

*so you did know what information was lacking.*
So from the conversation above, you were able to find out what the commenters think was lacking. Or, did you posses the knowledge for what was lacking yourself?

Comment: @Byebye: "*I have work during the day and I'm not looking at notifications from stack-overflow most of the time.*" We aren't obliged to wait for you to come back to the site. If your question is close-worthy, then we close it. "*Or, did you posses the knowledge for what was lacking yourself?*" I don't use Go or Clang, but your question here was explicit about using "c shared library", not compiling to "c", so it biased my thinking. Which is kind of my point: you said the right thing *here*, so why couldn't you say the right thing *there*?

Comment: @Byebye: That is, because you knew what you wanted, and because the commenters were talking about something that *wasn't* what you wanted, *you* had enough information to understand the misunderstanding. So it doesn't matter if I would have or not; what matters is that you *should have*.

Comment: *If your question is close-worthy, then we close it.*
As they should. Again, I don't care about the closure itself.

*what matters is that you should have.*
Well for one, there is nothing that I "should have" done. Either I know something, or I don't. If I don't, then I can't say I should have because at that point in time I lacked the knowledge I do possess now.

*you had enough information to understand the misunderstanding*
I asked for elaboration exactly because I didn't understand. Just because the information is there doesn't mean I understand it. Clearly I didn't.